# AttributeError: NDARRAY_SPEC while importing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I get this error

```
AttributeError: type object 'TypeSpecProto' has no attribute 
'NDARRAY_SPEC'
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QpKC.png)

Comment: I'm getting this error on a win 10 20H2 and python 3.8.5

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that your tensorflow version is not compatible with your python version.

Refer to [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) for knowing about compatible versions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move imports to `tensorflow.keras` domain. For example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, concatenate, Input, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Reshape, Concatenate, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Add, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.layers import add
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, RMSprop
from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this for me was to uninstall the packages tensorflow tensorboard and numpy and re-install them via pip by doing the following:

```
pip uninstall numpy tensorflow tensorboard
pip install --user --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: Please don't post same answer on multiple old question. Flagged them as **duplicate**.

Comment: I wanted to do that but unfortunately none of the questions had an accepted or upvoted answer. Thus, I wasn't able to flag them as duplicates.